# Detecting extreme values per group of attributes in a large dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, scikit-learn, scipy, anomaly-detection

I have a data set of items, their attributes and prices. So all categorical except the price. I want to build a model that can tell me if an item, with the same exact attribute, is extremely expensive or not.

The items vary in terms of size, location and material with affect the cost. So there are many items and many attributes per item.

What is the best approach to model this?

I have tried building distributions per group of item attributes, but ended up with huge amounts of models and time to choose the best distribution for each group.

I used `scipy.fit(data_group1)` for all the distributions in scipy selected the best using sum squared error (SSE). However, some histograms look similar but endup with different distributions and don't know which to select.

Feel free to recommend any alternative approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can regress price on the attributes and see which items have the highest residual, i.e. have a higher price than predicted by the overall regression.

If some observations might be considered as outliers, then using a outlier robust estimator instead of OLS would fit the majority of the data better and make outliers more visible. This can be done for example with statsmodels RLM model class.

The scipy distribution fit method estimates the parameters of a distribution when the parameters are constant across observations and does not take dependence on explanatory variables like the attributes here into account.

Comment: Thank you very much. My problem is that I have no labeled data to test. Your first suggestion is interesting but interpreting the threshold of residuals might be a little bit problematic.  Could you please further explain your last point, I'm interested since my theory understanding is lacking.

Comment: But you _do_ have labeled data. You said that you have the prices. What @user333700 is suggesting is that you build a model of price as a function of your attributes. Then,  you can predict the price on all of your examples and look at the residuals,  the differences between the predicted and actual values. The points that you are interested in are the points for which that is big.   I will suggest a different regression method - CART.  It builds a decision tree to predict the price. These are especially well suited for use with categorical predictors.